# Create a PowerApp's Approval Requests CDS Browse screen to show a link to the MS Flow Approval items

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, power-automate, ms-flow

I want to build a PowerApp which shows the MS Flow requests from this page:-

[image]

So first step i did is that i add a new PowerApp from CDS >> Approval Requests, as follow:-

[image]
[image]

Where i will get this Browse screen automatically:-

[image]

Now i need to modify this Built-in browse screen, to show URLs which will take the user to the MS flow Approve/Reject screen.. i found that i can access these data..

[image]

But i am not sure if i can use/benefit from this data to build a URL to the MS Flow Approvals items? so the user from the PowerApp Browser screen can click on a link which will open this MS flow screen to provide a response:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not really advised to modify the data coming in from the CDS. You would rather read the data into a collection variable on PowerApps and then build/manipulate your URL to redirect to the FLOW approval screen using the in-built Launch() function in PowerApps.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply .. can you advice more on this?